# Node.js v0.10 Stream2 API pipe "end" event

Tags: node.js

I upgraded to Node.js v0.10 with the new Streams2 API.

I noticed that now if I pipe to a file, when the "end" event is received the file might be still open and its size is 0.

for exmaple (using pdfkit):

```
http.get('http://www.example.com/test.jpg', function(res) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream('./test.jpg');
    res.on("end", function() {
        doc.image('./test.jpg');
    };

    res.pipe(file);
});
```

an error is thrown and the file size is 0.

but if I change it to `file.on("close"....` I get the desired result.

is this the correct behavior? should I use `file.on("close")` ?

Comment: pipe automatically closes dest.n stream when end is recieved on source stream. Can you post the full error and the code that is causing it

Comment: pdfkit throws an error for invalid image file type, if I look at the file its size is 0. as said in the question, changing the event to 'file.on("close")' results in the expected behavior..